# Angular Keycloak and Spring Boot 401 Error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, keycloak, http-status-code-401

I developed a couple of microservices in Spring Boot and secured them with Keycloak 15, I deployed the microservices onto an AWS EC2 instance in docker with an nginx reverse proxy with a letsencrypt certificate, suddenly some microservices always return a 401 error, when I inspected the response header in Postman / Chrome devtools, I get the following Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The iss claim is not valid", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
The application works perfectly on localhost

Please help  I have been tearing my head out for a couple of days now

Answer (score 0):

The issuer is based on the URL used to access Keycloak.
If the application requests the token with the DNS name that'll be the issuer, if it requests the token with the IP address that'll be the issuer. When verify access_token in keycloak adapter spring bot, it will call Keycloak get info config then verify signture of access_token and verify one by one field (the issuer field is one of the fields) in access_token if one of the fields doesn't match it will give 401 error

To fix issuer without following the request from the client, you configure the parameter KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL.

See more frontendUrl property is also required, to correctly generate the page redirects https://www.keycloak.org/docs/10.0/server_installation/index.html#default-provider. This is controlled by the KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL environment variable in official Docker image see https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

You have use reverse proxy, you can refer to here
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/10.0/server_installation/#identifying-client-ip-addresses
This implies use of proxy-address-forwarding=true which is controlled by PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true environment variable in official Docker image
see https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak